# Push notifications doesn't work on TestFlight

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, testflight

I use Firebase to send notifications:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {            
        FIRApp.configure()            
        let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.alert, UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.sound]
        let pushNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: notificationTypes, categories: nil)            
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(pushNotificationSettings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()            
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

        return true
    }        

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {            
        print("MessageID : \(userInfo["gcm_message_id"]!)")
        print (userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {            
        FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
        FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.prod)            
    }
```

I uploaded on Firebase two certificates: "APNs Development iOS" as development cert. and "Apple Push Services" as distribution (production) cert.:

[image: certificates]

I get notifications in development mode, but I didn't get notifications when I downloaded my app at TestFlight.

Comment: If you're using TestFlight I'm assuming it is an AdHoc build? AdHoc builds use the production APNS environment - does Firebase have access to your Production APNS push notification certificate?

Comment: No, I uploaded new version to App Store and added my e-mail in external testing. I also uploaded distribution certificate on Firebase

Comment: What do you mean by distribution certificate? What about the APNS certificate/p12/pem?

Comment: I uploaded "APNs Development iOS" certificate and "Apple Push Services" sertificate on Firebase. I attach screenshot: 
https://i.imgsafe.org/e931d227ff.png

Comment: If you uploaded to the app store, and use the development cert, that won't work. The app store builds use the production env and as such need a production cert.

Comment: I uploaded on Firebase two sertificates: "APNs Development iOS" as development cet. and "Apple Push Services" as distribution (production) cert.

Answer (score 0):

I removed sertificates and created new certificates and uploaded them again. Now it works.